# Pass parameter from one page to another using query string in WordPress web app

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having a strange problem with my WordPress web application.

Recently I have created a plugin on WordPress that job is to grab the key value on Query String following this link: http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress

I have followed exactly the same way the author has done.

I have created a sign up Template WordPress. I have created the template from the back-end code. Then I have added this template to a new page from my WordPress web app. This template helps user to type in their email address and save user details such as email, IP address into the database. This also generate a UNIQUE key value once user submit the form and redirect to a new page with the UNIQUE key value.

For the second page, I have created another Template and linked that to the page. When the user types in their email address on the first page and that information is saved, they are redirected with the UNIQUE key to this page.

From the second page I want to grab the key value from the QUERY STRING, such as the attached images.

(This is **working on my first hosting** server)

[image]

(This is **not working on my second hosting** server)

[image]

I could get the key value from first Hosting server few weeks ago, now I can't as shown in the second attached image.. Now i am just getting **NULL** return!?
Recently only the domain name was changed and after that the key passing functionality is not working any more!? Is there any issues for domain name changes for WordPress?

I have tested the same functionality from a second hosting server and it works fine and I can get the key value as shown in the first attached image.

But this functionality should work for the first hosting server.

I am just checking why the redirected page can't pass the key value in query string in WordPress? Is there any redirection issue?

What are the issues I need to check? 
If the same code work for the WordPress Hosting server, why can't it work on a different one?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, Can you please edit the post and re-add the images? I've just +1 you so you should have enough reputation to add images.

Comment: @MereDevelopment thanks for editing. can you please now have a look? I am struggling to solve it for last several days!